# Undeclared ‘yypvt’ variable in YACC action program

Tags: c, parsing, yacc

I was given a task to migrate an existing legacy parser generator (Yacc specification) from Solaris machine on to recent X86_64 Linux. I have no details about the Yacc version that is being used in Solaris. I took the spec and tried to push it through recent byacc. There were some function prototypes in the existing yacc specification that use a yacc variable 'yypvt'. However, byacc did not generate any variable with name yypvt. Therefore the generated parser code is failing to compile. I am new to yacc and I understand that yypvt is a pointer to stack. But, what is 'yypvt's equivalent in byacc ? In function prototype, what variable should replace yypvt?

Comment: This will be hard to convert. There should be no direct access to yypvt in the parser specs anyway, this sounds a bit hacky. Maybe you can eliminate this in a preparatory step?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how `yypvt` is being used in the parser specification?